# Scroll element to the top of an overflowed parent container

Tags: jquery, onclick, scrolltop

For some reason, I feel that it should be easy, but I can't get it to work and I can't seem to find a solution online.

I have a container (#container) set to overflow: scroll. Inside are 3 divs, and they all have the same height (100%) as the parent container. Each one of these divs contains a link.

Let's say that you scroll down and get half way through the second div, you should then be able to click the link in the second div, which would trigger the parent div to scroll up to the top of the container.

This is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div>
      <a href="#">link 1</a>
    </div>

    <div>
      <a href="#">link 2</a>
    </div>

    <div>
      <a href="#">link 3</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
}

div {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$("a").click(function() {
    // triggers parent div to scroll up to the parent container
});
```

I managed to use scrollTop to scroll to the div, but not to line up the div with the parent container.

I hope this makes sense. Thank you for your help.

**EDIT:**

Based on pilar1347's answer below, here's a Fiddle with the code in action: https://jsfiddle.net/julienfrog/w2oqsqc8/2/

Comment: Can you get an example running somewhere, like a fiddle?

Comment: See above. I added a Fiddle based on pilar1347's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be helpful to see an example of your question (a jsfiddle as ArcaneCraeda suggested), but is scrollTop(0) what you are looking for?

in your jQuery:

```
$("a").click(function(){
    $("#container").scrollTop(0);
});
```

This should scroll to the top of the #container div when a link is clicked.

However, if what you are looking for is for the selected div to snap to the top of the #container, then you might want something like this:

```
$("a").click(function(){
    var clicked_idx = $(this).parent().index();
    var div_height = $(this).parent().height();
    var scroll_to = clicked_idx * div_height;

    $("#container").scrollTop(scroll_to);
})
```

Note: This would only work if all child divs are the same height.

Comment: Thanks. That's perfect! index() is what I was missing. I learned something new. I will create a Fiddle and add it to my question. Thanks again!